# Is there anyone processed the LDR file from zenmuse L1 using python?

Tags: lidar

my name is Edy. I am new user of python and Lidar data. It would be great if there is someone who wants to share the LDR file processing from zenmuse L1 using python. I had tried using DJI Terra, but I belive that process the LDR using python will give us more information. Thank yoU!

I have not tried anything yet.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to have the necessary libraries installed in your Python environment. Few popular libraries:

NumPy, Open3D, PDAL

To start processing your LDR data, you'll need to load the point cloud from the LDR file. You can use the appropriate library functions to read the LDR data into a suitable data structure, such as a NumPy array or a point cloud object provided by a library like Open3D.

Once the data is loaded, you can perform various operations on it, such as filtering, segmentation, registration, or extracting specific features. The choice of operations depends on your specific goals and the information you want to extract from the LDR data.

Here's a simple example to get you started with loading and visualizing an LDR point cloud using Open3D:

python

```
import open3d as o3d

# Load LDR point cloud
point_cloud = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("path/to/your/ldr/file.ldr")

# Visualize the point cloud
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([point_cloud])
```

This code assumes you have Open3D installed and have specified the path to your LDR file. It will load the point cloud from the file and display it using a visualization window.

From here, you can explore the various functions and algorithms provided by the libraries I mentioned earlier to perform more advanced processing on your LDR data.

Remember, LDR data processing can be complex, so it's essential to have a clear understanding of your objectives and familiarize yourself with the available tools and techniques. Don't hesitate to consult the documentation and examples provided by the libraries for more in-depth information.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your very clear instruction! I ran your code by installing open3d using pip in the first step, which was successful, but I ran the whole code:

import open3d as o3d

# Load LDR point cloud
point_cloud = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("path/to/your/ldr/file.ldr")

# Visualize the point cloud
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([point_cloud])

And the open3d window shows up. Nothing happened for one hour +, and the code continued loading. Is it normal? Again, thank you so much for your efforts in explaining this in very detail!

Comment: May I know what the result that should appear for this process..?

Comment: Open3d does not support .ldr format https://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/file_io.html